# How should I give an accurate job title to my voluntary work?

Tags: resume, linkedin, title, volunteering

I recently did some voluntary work for a large NGO, and I would like to add this to both my CV and LinkedIn profile. The issue is that I have no idea what an appropriate job title might be. They asked for statistics advice on a manuscript/grey paper they are working on, so I've tentatively called this a "statistical consultant" role. I'm torn between thinking this is self-aggrandising, but also the best literal description.

A note: I have sent away this question to the person who requested the advice, with no response yet. I will update if I get one.

**Edit:** More detail on the work itself, as requested: I was sent two manuscripts, a costing analysis, and a very large dataset of a three year project. I was asked to give my opinion on the validity of the study design and statistical analysis, to read and comment on the manuscripts, and to explore the dataset for other potentially interesting questions and associations. I was fairly thorough and ended up writing around 800 words in comments and suggestions.

I also made suggestions for potential further research and wrote two Stata '.do' files to support these suggestions. I would estimate the work took around 40 hours, conducted in my spare time over the course of a couple of weeks.

Perhaps this particular context matters, too; this was initially intended to be a placement where I would work in-person at a research centre, but this was interrupted by COVID-19. I have also agreed to participate in continuing projects using the same data remotely until it becomes feasible I can undertake a full-time placement in the future.

Comment: This will depend heavily on the scope and level of accountability you had. Answers can probably focus on both cases but it might help you to provide some basic info on that here already.

Comment: If it was volunteer work why do you need a job title? Why not list it as volunteer work and list what you did as a volunteer?

Comment: Several online job application forms and profiles require something in the job title field under a "voluntary work" section, including LinkedIn, so "volunteer" under "voluntary work" seems redundant. I also think it would be better to indicate the nature of the work in the title, as there's many different types of volunteer roles even within this one NGO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking them was probably the "correct" course of action - if nothing else because it's key for yourself and the organisation to be on the same page when it comes to answering what your role was should they ever be contacted for a reference or as part of a background check, although that is more likely to be a thing for paid positions than volunteer ones.

In the meantime (or if you never get an answer back) you can always list your position as "Volunteer -  Performed Statistical Consultation", you're making it clear that you were a volunteer and getting the description of what you did in but without explicitly *claiming* the title of "Statistical Consultant"

> thinking this is self-aggrandising

It is - but that's sort of the point of a CV, as long as it's *true* you're supposed to make yourself sound as impressive as possible!